# BroadSword attached to a Player jumps ahead 2 pixels when moving player in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

Here is the deal. I have a player that has a broadsword within a tiled game map. The broadsword is attached to the players location, and when the left mouse button is pressed, it rotates around the player to simulate a "swing". However, whenever I move the player when im attacking with the broadsword, the broadsword which is represented by a 5x5 blue dot, jumps ahead 2 pixels of the direction im heading in.

I have had this problem with the player, however it was easily fixed with using `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)`

This time, no matter what I do using the projection matrix, the blue dot either jumps 2 pixels ahead, or jumps 10-20px ahead then becomes normal.

Here is the render method for the **BroadSword** class, where I have tested multiple scenarios, and I have included the scenario that is the closest to the non-bouncing:

```
...
public void render() {
    if(!isSwinging)
        return;
    //Using a new Batch object, not the one from the Main class and
    // setting the projection matrix to camera.combined after we draw the broadsword
    //  (a blue dot) is the only way that partially works.
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture, broadSwordPos.x, broadSwordPos.y);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.disableBlending();
    batch.end();
    
}
...
```

The method above is the only method that partially works (At the start when I start attacking, the broadsword jumps ahead 10 to 20 pixels ahead for a fraction of a second, then returns to the desired position)

Any other method, such as using the **SpriteBatch** object used in the Main class
(batch pasted to the gameworld, which is pasted to the player, which is then pasted to the broadsword)
or setting the projection matrix before the draw, dosen't work, and causes the bouncing 2px ahead problem.

What is wrong here? (Please let me know if I need to provide more code)